# I lost some reputation. Is my privilege also gone?

Tags: support, reputation

For 2 days I have had the privilege to edit questions and answers. Yesterday I lost some reputation points and now I have less then 2000. Is the privilege also gone?

Comment: have you tested it? :)

Comment: No, not at all. but when I look at my profile it seems so.  https://askubuntu.com/users/966203/nobody

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, when your reputation dips below the level of a given privilege, you *lose* that privilege until you gain enough rep to go above that requirement level again.  This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as part of reputation levels being tied to privileges.

Comment: Oh, okay, I will it memorized.

Comment: *This is status-bydesign as part of reputation levels being tied to permissions:* Did you mean *privileges*?

Comment: yes kulfy but I was tired